# Converting Swift code to Objective-C errors

Tags: objective-c, swift

Im try to convert from swift to Objective-C, but have errors

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    print(url)

    let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)

    let host = urlComponents?.host ?? ""

    print(host)

    return true
}
```

In object try:

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    printf("%s", url);

    NSURLComponents * const urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true);

    NSString * const host = urlComponents.host ?? ""

    printf(host);
    return true;
    }
```

But have error

> Implicit declaration of function 'URLComponents' is invalid in C99

Comment: what did you tried so far ?

Comment: @RatulSharker add code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    printf("%s", url);

    NSURLComponents *  urlComponents = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:true];

    NSString *  host = urlComponents.host;

    NSLog(host);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this., It will work without error...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
   NSLog(@"%@", url);
   NSURLComponents * const urlComponents = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:true];
   NSString * const host = urlComponents.host;
   NSLog(@"%@", host);
   return true;
}
```